# How to navigate to a specific route without adding in the url in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using `react-router` and I have some routes nested like `"/stories"` and `"/stories/:storyId"` now my problem is that I have a component that is a single story and uses this specific `storyId` to navigate to the route `"/stories/:storyId"` on clicking it to see that story details. The problem comes that this single component can be rendered in another route like `"/bookmarks"` and if I use the hook `useNavigate` and pass it  the `storyId` when I click the component it navigates to `"/bookmarks/:storyId"` and I want it to go to `"/stories/:storyId"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component that is rendered on different subroutes should use absolute link paths instead of relative paths. The difference between relative and absolute paths is the leading `"/"` character. Paths starting with `"/"` are absolute from the root where the app is hosted, while paths otherwise are treated as relative from the current matched path.

For example, instead of

```
<Link to={`../${storyId}`}>{storyId}</Link>

... or ...

<Link to={`${storyId}`}>{storyId}</Link>

... or ...

navigate(`../${storyId}`);

... or ...

navigate(`${storyId}`);
```

which only links relatively to a sibling or child path from the current path, use an absolute path

```
<Link to={`/stories/${storyId}`}>{storyId}</Link>

... or ...

navigate(`/stories/${storyId}`);
```